# How to solve error restarting apache Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Question originally [posted in Spanish, on es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/301648/error-al-reiniciar-apache-ubuntu), by [mnsperez97](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/143376/mnsperez97):

> I have a problem with the connection to Apache, after restarting it
> with the `sudo service apache2 restart` command, I get this error
>
> > Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with
> > error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl
> > -xe" for details.
>
> and then when entering localhost it does not let me in and it makes me
> worse, when I run `sudo journalctl -xe` he told me the following but
> still I do not find the error, if you could help me I would be very
> grateful
>
> EDIT: run the `systemctl status apache2.service` command and this
> appears to me
>
> ```
> apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
>    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>   Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
>            └─apache2-systemd.conf
>    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-10-17 12:20:34 -04; 29min ago
>   Process: 21198 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>   Process: 7385 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>   Process: 23453 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>  Main PID: 1059 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
> oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco apachectl[23453]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 47 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/cms.local.conf:
> oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco apachectl[23453]: order takes one argument, 'allow,deny', 'deny,allow', or 'mutual-failure'
> oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco apachectl[23453]: Action 'start' failed.
> oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco apachectl[23453]: The Apache error log may have more information.
> oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
> oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> oct 17 12:20:34 pcarrasco systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is common due to problems in your configuration

it may be the port configuration

lock at the [log file](http://blog.codeasite.com/how-do-i-find-apache-http-server-log-files/) (pass can be found as ErrorLog in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)

or try to undo what you changed in the configuration files till you find the problem

Comment: Search for the route and I do not use it ubuntu 18.09, when I use the command `sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` it tells me that the route does not exist

Comment: if you are using apache only you'll find it in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf/`

Comment: if you are running lampp/xampp stack then it will be normally `/opt/lampp/etc/`... or in other words  `/{dir-to-stack}/lampp/etc`